# AWS CloudFormation Template not getting EndpointURL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to run the AWS demo stack for AWS X Ray and I keep getting this error:
*Attribute 'EndpointURL' does not exist. Rollback requested by user.*

I don't understand it since EndpointURL should be an output for the environment resource.

Here's the yml file

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: An AWS Elastic application that uses DynamoDB.
Parameters:
  emailAddress:
    Type: String
    Default: UPDATEME
Resources:
  function:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: random-name
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs18.x
      CodeUri: function/.
      Description: Generate random names
      Timeout: 10
      # Function's execution role
      Policies:
        - AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
        - AWSXrayWriteOnlyAccess
        - AmazonSNSFullAccess
      Tracing: Active
      Environment:
        Variables:
          TOPIC_ARN: !Ref notificationTopic
  application:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: Scorekeep
      Description: RESTful web API in Java with Spring that provides an HTTP interface for creating and managing game sessions and users.
  version:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Ref application
      SourceBundle: ./package.zip
  environment:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Ref application
      EnvironmentName: BETA
      SolutionStackName: "64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.4.10 running Corretto 8"
      OptionSettings:
        - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
          OptionName: AWS_REGION
          Value: !Ref AWS::Region
        - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
          OptionName: NOTIFICATION_TOPIC
          Value: !Ref notificationTopic
        - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
          OptionName: NOTIFICATION_EMAIL
          Value: !Ref emailAddress
        - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
          OptionName: USER_TABLE
          Value: !Ref userTable
        - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
          OptionName: SESSION_TABLE
          Value: !Ref sessionTable
        - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
          OptionName: GAME_TABLE
          Value: !Ref gameTable
        - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
          OptionName: MOVE_TABLE
          Value: !Ref moveTable
        - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
          OptionName: STATE_TABLE
          Value: !Ref stateTable
        - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
          OptionName: AWS_XRAY_TRACING_NAME
          Value: !Ref application
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
          OptionName: IamInstanceProfile
          Value: !Ref instanceProfile
      VersionLabel: !Ref version
  instanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: /
      Roles:
        - !Ref role
  role:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ec2.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSXRayDaemonWriteAccess
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: resources
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Sid: ResourceAccess
                Action:
                  - '*'
                Effect: Allow
                Resource:
                  - 'arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/scorekeep-*'
                  - 'arn:aws:sns:*:*:scorekeep-*'
                  - 'arn:aws:lambda:*:*:function/random-name'
        - PolicyName: beanstalk
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Sid: BucketAccess
                Action:
                  - 's3:Get*'
                  - 's3:List*'
                  - 's3:PutObject'
                Effect: Allow
                Resource: arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk*
              - Sid: MetricsAccess
                Action:
                  - 'cloudwatch:PutMetricData'
                Effect: Allow
                Resource: '*'
      Path: /
  notificationTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
  userTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      KeySchema:
        HashKeyElement: {AttributeName: id, AttributeType: S}
      ProvisionedThroughput: {ReadCapacityUnits: 2, WriteCapacityUnits: 2}
  sessionTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      KeySchema:
        HashKeyElement: {AttributeName: id, AttributeType: S}
      ProvisionedThroughput: {ReadCapacityUnits: 2, WriteCapacityUnits: 2}
  gameTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: "id"
          AttributeType: "S"
        - AttributeName: "session"
          AttributeType: "S"
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: "id"
          KeyType: "HASH"
      GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
        - IndexName: "session-index"
          KeySchema:
            - AttributeName: "session"
              KeyType: "HASH"
          ProvisionedThroughput: {ReadCapacityUnits: 2, WriteCapacityUnits: 2}
          Projection: { ProjectionType: ALL }
      ProvisionedThroughput: {ReadCapacityUnits: 2, WriteCapacityUnits: 2}
  moveTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: "id"
          AttributeType: "S"
        - AttributeName: "game"
          AttributeType: "S"
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: "id"
          KeyType: "HASH"
      GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
        - IndexName: "game-index"
          KeySchema:
            - AttributeName: "game"
              KeyType: "HASH"
          ProvisionedThroughput: {ReadCapacityUnits: 2, WriteCapacityUnits: 2}
          Projection: { ProjectionType: ALL }
      ProvisionedThroughput: {ReadCapacityUnits: 2, WriteCapacityUnits: 2}
  stateTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: "id"
          AttributeType: "S"
        - AttributeName: "game"
          AttributeType: "S"
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: "id"
          KeyType: "HASH"
      GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
        - IndexName: "game-index"
          KeySchema:
            - AttributeName: "game"
              KeyType: "HASH"
          ProvisionedThroughput: {ReadCapacityUnits: 2, WriteCapacityUnits: 2}
          Projection: { ProjectionType: ALL }
      ProvisionedThroughput: {ReadCapacityUnits: 2, WriteCapacityUnits: 2}
Outputs:
  endpoint:
    Description: Website URL
    Value: !GetAtt environment.EndpointURL
    Export:
      Name: !Join ["-", [!Ref "AWS::StackName","endpoint"]]
```

I've tried to look into the documentation but couldn't find any help.

Comment: Were all the resources created successfully? I see two possible reasons: 1) you did not provide a name to the instanceProfile, the other might be that you need an explicit dependency in there. But most likely, you can find out in the UI, by looking at the first failure in your template.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will try to add a name to instanceProfile and see how it goes. Every other resource was created successfully and the first failure was the one mentioned above.